# Unexpected error when trying to use NSLog()

Tags: iphone, ios, scrape

I'm new to iOS develoment, and I'm trying to write an app that can scrape a website (HTML). Scraping google is just an example - I'm planning on scraping something a bit more complex...

My code is as follows:

```
#import "KppleViewController.h"
#import "TFHpple.h"

@implementation KppleViewController
@synthesize theButton;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"button Pressed");
    NSURL *url          = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"];
    NSData *htmlData    = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
    TFHpple *xpathParse = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];  
    NSArray *elements   = [xpathParse searchWithXPathQuery:@"//h3"];
    TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *h3Tag = [element content];  
    NSLog(@"x",h3Tag);
}
```

The problem is that I get an error when I attempt to write to console (via `NSLog`) to see if anything worked. The error that I get is "Data argument not used by format string"

I've searched all over the internet, to no avail. If I comment out the NSLog to see if I my previous code is correct, I get an error about the variable immediately above the NSlog (h3Tag) declared but not being used.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

I'm also open to any other methods of scraping HTML...

Answer (score 6):

You're being confused by this line:

```
NSLog(@"x",h3Tag);
```

All this line does is log the string `x`. The second argument is completely unused. What you want is something like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", h3Tag);
```

or perhaps a bit more descriptive:

```
NSLog(@"h3Tag: %@", h3Tag);
```

The token `%@` inside of the format string indicates that this is where the next argument will be printed. You may want to read up on the [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1) or on [Formatting String Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943-CJBEAEHH) in general.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I added the "x" to  NSLog(@"x" while troubleshooting the problem. I had already attempted NSLOG(h3Tag), which also produced an error. The real issue, I believe, is caused by TFHpple.h include. When I compile and go over to the "issue navigator" in xcode (VIEW->Navigators->Show Issue Navigator), I have this error: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TFHpple", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in KppleViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: `NSLog(h3Tag)` is also incorrect. If `h3Tag` contains any `%@` tokens then you'll crash. In any case, the error you just quoted means that `TFHpple.m` isn't being compiled into your project. You should make sure it's part of your target.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
NSLog(@"%@", h3Tag);
```

or

```
NSLog(h3Tag);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"x = %@",h3Tag);
Above line prints the value of h3Tag.

For more help about NSLog refer link:  [http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSLog]
```